# "No Rakefile found" when I run "rake gems:refresh_specs"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rakefile

When I run my app I get this error:

```
config.gem: Unpacked gem rakismet-0.3.6 in vendor/gems has no specification file. 
Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
```

And when I run:

```
rake gems:refresh_specs
```

I get:

```
No Rakefile found
```

I've tried the rake command from various directories within the application hierarchy with no success.

Comment: And you have this `Rakefile` in your directory ?

Comment: No. What type of Rakefile do I need? Is there a pre-written one that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate a rails application you get a Rakefile created in the base directory of that application. This is the directory you should be calling `rake gem:refresh_specs` from.